# How to avoid multiple try catch for undefined values (by using if/else or some other way) while fetching border values from Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am fetching border values from the sheet and creating an HTML table in Gmail. I am new to Javascript (google script) and struggling to optimize the code.

I am using advanced sheets property to fetch border values for each cell. If the border doesn't exist, rather than returning "none", the values are undefined. Hence, using try-catch to set the border value to "none".

I read a few blogs which said try-catch should be minimally used and it slows down the code. Is there a way to improve this code as I am using try-catch for each border (top, left, right and bottom) for every cell?

The error returned without try-catch is 'Cannot read property "0.0" from undefined'.

```
  //Creating an array of border values by assigning the range values 
var aBorderValues = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetID, {ranges: borderRange, fields: "sheets/data/rowData/values/userEnteredFormat/borders"})));
// Getting the top border style
    try
    {
      var topBorder =aBorderValues.sheets[0].data[0].rowData[i].values[j].userEnteredFormat.borders.top.style;  
    }
    catch (etop)
    {
      topBorder = "none";           
    }
```

Comment: That is always an issue with long chained expressions (and why they're considered bad practice by some). If any expression returns an unexpected value, the whole thing fails. Wrapping in *try..catch* just makes it worse. You really should only ever use them when you **know** each expression will return a suitable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write something like `get` in lodash and provide the path to the property you want to access as an array of strings and/or numbers:

```js
function get (object, path, defaultValue) {
  return object === undefined //object at current path is undefined
    ? defaultValue //return default value
    : path.length === 0 //no more items in path
      ? object //return value at completed path (path.length === 0)
      : object[path[0]] === undefined //go one level deeper
        ? defaultValue //there is nothing one level deeper, return default
        : get(object[path[0]], path.slice(1), defaultValue); //recursively call itself
}
const test = [{ name: 'hi' }];
console.log(get(test, [0, 'name']));
console.log(get(test, [1, 'name'], 'default value'));
console.log(
  get(undefined, [1, 'name'], 'other default value'),
);
//index of array does not have to be a number:
console.log(get(test, ['0', 'name']));
```

Comment: @HMR: Thanks. As I am new to Javascript, am not quite clear on what should be the 'object' and 'path' in this context? Should the object be 'topBorder' or aBorderValues or should I modify/ introduce an object and a path? And what is the use of object here?

Comment: @UmangSurana object can be anything, for example `window` if you want `window.location.hash.length` you can do `get(window, ['location','hash','length'])` and if you want `88` to be the value if location.hash.length doesn't exist you can provide a default value: `get(window, ['location','hash','length'],88)`

Comment: @tehhowch Updated to remove arrow function syntax.

Comment: @HMR thanks for the example. It really helped in the understanding and now the undefined error is not showing up. Now the code line is `const topBorder =  get (aBorderValues, ['sheets[0]','data[0]','rowData[i]','values[j]','userEnteredFormat','borders','top','style'], 'none');` which is always returning 'none'. Does it work in the same way in For loop or does it require some modification? Or am I missing something here.

Comment: @UmangSurana it should be: `get(aBorderValues,['sheets',0,'data',0,'rowData',i,'values',j,'userEnteredFormat','borders','top','style'],'none')`

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It is working great. Has reduced runtime as well as readability of the code.